# Which one is correct? "decide suddenly to stop" or "decide to suddenly stop"

Tags: grammar, adverbs

You can't decide to **suddenly** stop going to school.

You can't decide **suddenly** to stop going to school

Comment: Personally, I would prefer _suddenly decide to stop_.

Comment: It simply depends on whether you want the suddenness to apply to ***deciding*** or ***stopping***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, where I infer a parent talking to a child, both of those sentences are natural and will be understood to have the exact same meaning, which is roughly, "*You cannot simply decide you're going to stop going to school.*" The word "suddenly" here actually means something like, "on your own" or "without any discussion or consultation", and doesn't actually mean "abruptly".

That said, the two sentences don't have the same literal meaning. To make things clearer, let's change the context slightly to "stop the car", rather than "stop going to school", and let's remove all the distracting stuff:

1. She decided **to suddenly** stop the car.
2. She decided **suddenly to** stop the car.

In sentence 1, "suddenly" modifies "stop the car", so she decided that she would cause the car to stop very quickly, likely by stepping hard on the brakes. The sentence doesn't say when she decided to do it, nor when she did it. This would make sense, for instance, if she's trying to make someone else in the car spill their drink, or if she's trying to scare someone following too close behind her.

In sentence 2, "suddenly" modifies "decide", so she decided very quickly that she would stop the car. The sentence implies but doesn't require that she did so immediately, and doesn't describe how abruptly she stopped the car. This would apply in a situation where she realized she needed to make an emergency phone call, so decided to stop at the side of the road, or pull into a parking lot. She may have slowed the car down gently, rather than hitting the brakes hard.

Comment: You did it great, thanks a lot. 

Answer (score 4):

In the first you "suddenly stop".  In the second you "decide suddenly".  So the adverb modifies a different verb.

The two verbs are chained together, so we understand that a sudden decision will result in a sudden stopping.  So at some level the meaning is near the same.

The difference is what it implies you can do:

> You can't decide to suddenly stop going to school (but you can decide to give notice that you intend to stop going to school in the future)

> You can't decide suddenly to stop going to school (but you can decide in a slow and deliberate manner)

And, as noted in comments "suddenly decide" might be better than "decide suddenly".

Comment: Not to mention things like ***Suddenly**, you can't decide to stop going to school* (until recently, you *could* make such a decision, but the rules have just changed with little or no notice).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't decide to **suddenly** stop going to school.
2. You can't decide **suddenly** to stop going to school

I don't see any difference in *meaning* between sentences 1 and 2, the only difference is the position of the adverb ‘suddenly’.

In the first sentence, it [*splits the infinitive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive) phrase:
"…**to** *suddenly* **stop** going to school*"

In the second, the adverb goes BEFORE the infinitive phrase
"…*suddenly* **to stop going** *to school*"

A third alternative would be to position the adverb BEFORE the verb DECIDE

3. "You **can't** *suddenly* **decide** to stop going to school*"

For me–your mileage may differ–the meaning in all three examples is exactly the same, i.e. the decision to stop going to school was made *suddenly*.

> A **split infinitive** is a grammatical construction in which an adverb or adverbial phrase separates the "to" and "infinitive" constituents of what was traditionally called the full infinitive, but is more commonly known in modern linguistics as the to-infinitive (e.g. to go). In the history of English language aesthetics, the split infinitive was often deprecated, despite its prevalence in colloquial speech. The opening sequence of the *Star Trek* television series contains a well-known example, "**to boldly go** where no man has gone before", wherein the adverb *boldly* was said to split the full infinitive, *to go*. Multiple words may split a to-infinitive, such as: "The population is expected **to more than double** in the next ten years."
>
> In the 19th century, some linguistic prescriptivists sought to introduce a rule proscribing the split infinitive, and the resulting conflict had considerable cultural importance. The construction still renders disagreement, but it could be argued that modern English usage guides have largely dropped the objection to it.
>
> Source: *Wikipedia*